# Problema al retornar en WebApi c#

Tags: c#, controller, webapi

tengo un servicio **WebApi** en **`C#`** que se encarga de resolver una ecuación y devolver sus raíces.

Sucede que no estoy pudiendo devolver `NoContent();`, no me reconoce el método.

Y cuando le doy:

```
 string s = "No existen raices reales";
 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, s);
```

me dice que no se puede convertir no se puede convertir `HttpResponseMessage` en `IHttpActionResult`.

El código de mi función del **`controller`** **WebApi** es :

```
// GET: api/Bhaskara/a/b/c
        [Route("{a}/{b}/{c}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult getBhaskara(int a, int b, int c)
        {
            try{
                if (a < 1 || a > 100 || b < 1 || b > 100 || c < 1 || c > 100)
                    return BadRequest("Los números deben comprenderse entre 0 y 100 inclusive.");

                //Declaración y cálculo de raíces
                double raizNegativa, raizPositiva;
                raizNegativa = (-b - (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
                raizPositiva = (-b + (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);


                if (Double.IsNaN(raizNegativa) || Double.IsNaN(raizPositiva))
                {
                    //Si alguna raiz no existiese
                    string s = "No existen raices reales";
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, s);
                }
                else if (raizPositiva != raizNegativa)
                {
                    //Si ambas son diferentes se devuelven las dos.
                    string[] raices = new string[2];
                    raices[0] = raizNegativa.ToString("0.#####"); // Formateo amigable de string
                    raices[1] = raizPositiva.ToString("0.#####");
                    return Ok(raices);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Si son iguales devuelve una de ellas.
                    return Ok(raizNegativa);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                return NotFound();
            }

        }
```

No puedo ver claramente que es lo que se me esta escapando.

Yo pensaba que con simplemente `NoContent()` podía solucionar, pero me dice:

> "NoContent() no existe en el contexto actual".

Lo que quisiera hacer es devolver un **204** con un mensaje en el data del estilo **"No existen raices reales"**, o algo por el estilo.

Gracias!

Saludos

Comment: No creo que debas retornar un `.createResponse` tu metodo retorna una interfaz de `ActionResult` deberías de retornar algo como esto `return Ok(product);` , si quieres dejar el `CreateResponse` , debes de cambiar `ActionResult` por **`HttpResponseMessage`** y puedes cambiar el `return Ok(raices);` por **`HttpStatusCode.OK`** si lo cambias o Puedes dejar el ActionResult y retornar `return BadRequest("No existen raices reales");`

Comment: Marca el check verde al costado de la respuesta que te ha solucionado el caso, con eso estarás colaborando con la buena salud del sitio :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba de esta manera:

```
            if (Double.IsNaN(raizNegativa) || Double.IsNaN(raizPositiva))
            {
                //Si alguna raiz no existiese
                string s = "No existen raices reales";
                //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, s);
                return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
            }
```

Pero debes tener en cuenta que un **StatusCode 204** no devuelve **nada**, así que si quieres devolver un **mensaje de error** deberás hacerlo mediante un `BadRequest()`:

```
return BadRequest("No existen raices reales");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Rafael!! . Tu respuesta me sirvio. El mensaje lo puedo controlar igual desde el llamado a la api cuando el response me de el status, ahi modifico el msj. Gracias!

Comment: @sammael115 Estupendo!, recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han sido útiles para resolver tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar utilizando ResponseMessageResult para regresar tu respuesta HttpStatusCode tu defines el código de error a regresar [codigos para HTTP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=netframework-4.8)

ejemplo:

```
return new ResponseMessageResult(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, s));
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno como te lo dije en el comentario tu error esta en esta linea:

```
string s = "No existen raices reales";
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, s);
```

Debes de cambiarla por esto:

```
string s = "No existen raices reales";
return BadRequest(s);
```

o solo dejar el **`return`** con el mensaje ya que la declaración de la variables es innecesaria.

```
return BadRequest("No existen raices reales");
```

**Por que ?**
Ya que tu método retorna una interfaz de `IHttpActionResult` no puedes retornar métodos de la clase `HttpResponseMessage`